# XCode Alignment Constraints

Tags: xcode, alignment, constraints

How to implement objects in a View (Buttons, whatever) and align those objects perfectly in Landscape mode and Portrait mode?

It seems impossible and the alignment constraints editor (XCode 5) is cryptic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

This is the result:

[image: Screenshot in landscape mode]

[image: Screenshot in portrait mode]

I have attached a link with an explanatory video. Writing it is too complex.

[XCode Alignment Constraints Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5Fr3QGFOj8&feature=youtu.be)